# Can't Run Ubuntu SDK Apps in Emulator

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, ubuntu-emulator

> Ubuntu 14.04.1
> Qt Creator 3.1.1
> Ubuntu Touch: Image version 189 & 179

I recently upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04 LTS (with Ubuntu SDK installed, and I did re-enable the ubuntu-sdk repository) and finally able to get the Ubuntu emulator working. However, the SDK doesn't seem to be able to run created app in the emulator. It stucks at **"Waiting for your emulator to get ready"**, even though the emulator has already been successfully started with **Device Status: Ready**.

[image: Waiting for your emulator to get ready]

Are there any solutions? Please tell me if there are more informations I should provide. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Tim "to". Upgraded to 14.04 from 12.04 = upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04 = 12.04 -> 14.04 :)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, the main difference being the fact that I started with a fresh 14.04 installation.

I was able to fix this problem after reading [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/ubuntu-touch-emulator-installation-and.html) tutorial.

First thing I did was I purged *ubuntu-emulator* and *ubuntu-emulator-runtime* and have removed *ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa*.
Then, following [the instructions](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/ubuntu-touch-emulator-installation-and.html), I've added the *phablet-team/tools* ppa and then installed *ubuntu-emulator*.

Lastly, I've made a new emulator with this command **(I think I could have fixed the problem with THIS command only! Maybe You can try just this one first)**:

```
$ sudo ubuntu-emulator create UbuntuTouch --arch=i386 --channel=ubuntu-touch/utopic-proposed
```

Now I can run apps on this emulator from the QtCreator, and I get a **green** status icon for this emulator instead of **orange**!

Hope this helps! :D